# Centos: Adduser/Passwd/Sudoer Script

Tags: centos, sudo

I'm currently running a VPS on CentOS. I have an application running in the background and it will run a script under `sudo` to either disable or enable any account.

So what I'm trying to create is a script that creates an account, adds a password and adds the users under "etc/sudoers".

The script is being run as root so there shouldn't be any permission errors. How would I come to create this script?

Answer (score 3):

I've been looking for the same thing, the best I've come up with thus far is to add a unix group in the `/etc/sudoers` file like this:

```
# Members of the sftpadmin group may gain root privileges
%sftpadmin          ALL=(ALL)       ALL
```

And then when adding a user to the system add them to this group using `useradd`:

```
useradd ... -g sftpadmin ... newuser
```

Also the `/etc/sudoers` file includes a group for this very purpose called wheel. It's commented out but you could uncomment it and then start adding users that you want to give full access to into the wheel group. The `/etc/sudoers` file includes 2 examples, one that will challenge people with their password and one that won't.

```
## Allows people in group wheel to run all commands
# %wheel    ALL=(ALL)   ALL

## Same thing without a password
# %wheel    ALL=(ALL)   NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Also as an alternative take a look at this stackoverflow post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323957/how-do-i-edit-etc-sudoers-from-a-script. It discusses how to make a custom script that can do automatically what you'd do when running `visudo` and manually edit the `/etc/sudoers` file.

Comment: Using a group is definitely the right approach. It's not just a workaround for not having to edit `sudoers`, it makes maintenance easier overall.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [useradd](http://www.mediacollege.com/cgi-bin/man/page.cgi?topic=useradd) command to create a user but you shouldn't really automate adding the user to the sudoers file. This file is normally edited via the [visudo](http://www.gratisoft.us/sudo/man/1.7.5/visudo.man.html) command. Editing it directly, especially in an automated fashion may results in errors rendering the file corrupt. Certainly not a situation you will wish to deal with.